# Why can't I pass output variable as a parameter to function block constructor in IEC61131-3 structured text (TwinCAT3)?

Tags: plc, twincat, st, structured-text, iec61131-3

I have a function block `A` that has one variable `output` (defined in the `FUNCTION_BLOCK A` method) and this `FB_init` method:

```
METHOD FB_init : BOOL
    VAR_INPUT
        bInitRetains : BOOL; // if TRUE, the retain variables are initialized (warm start / cold start)
        bInCopyCode : BOOL;  // if TRUE, the instance afterwards gets moved into the copy code (online change)
    END_VAR
    
    VAR_OUTPUT
        output : REAL := 0;
    END_VAR

THIS^.output := output;
```

When I call this constructor as follows:

```
a : A(output => outputLocal);
```

- I get syntax error: `Identifier 'output' not defined`. But I did defined
  this parameter in the constructor method.
- When I try to compile the project I get another error: `No matching FB_init method found for instantiation of A`
- Does anyone know where is the problem? And how I can pass variable as
  an output parameter to function block?
- I want basically to link the `localoutput` to the variable `output` (of the FB `A`) in the FB constructor.

Comment: This is very strange call to me `a : A(output => outputLocal);` Where do you have such a construction? What is `a :`? It looks like declaration, but you cannot call FB in declarations. If it is assignment and you missed `=` then it also does not make sense.

Comment: It is a declaration and I am calling `FB_init` method.  I want to link FB's internal variable `output` to local variable `outputlocal`

Comment: As I understand methods has access to all FB local variables. You can `outputlocal := 1` right in the Method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By declaring output in the `VAR_OUTPUT` section of the method, you are making it a local *output* variable to the method, not an *input* variable.

You need to declare a `VAR_OUTPUT` in the `FunctionBlock` and a `VAR_INPUT` in the constructor and assign the input variable from the constructor to the output variable of the `FunctionBlock`—probably by `REF=`, or you'll just get the value.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you technically can have output parameters in the `FB_Init`-method, you can't get them out from the call of FB_Init. My guess is that it has to do with how the object is being constructed in time, and therefore it makes no sense.

The more important questions is:
What are you trying to achieve? In the above example it seems you are trying to access the parameter output, which I assume is an output of the entire function block, from the FB_Init-call? You seem to be writing to an output of the function block, from an output of an method call, which doesn't make any sense.

If you only want to pass a parameter as an output from a function block, why not provide it as an input-parameter in that case? (either by copy or by reference)?

Comment: I want basically to link / connect the `localoutput` to the variable `output` (of the FB `A`). Normally I can do it with the `=>` sign but in this case it is not working. I also edited the question.

Comment: But what you are doing (and what is not possible), is that you are trying to access the output-variable of the method FB_Init. If you want to access the variable `output`, you can just call the FB in the body, like: `A(output => myVariable)`

Comment: Ah I see. So the only way to access the `function_block` `output` variable is within the main code right? It can't be done IN the constructor?

Comment: I still don't understand the use case of why you would want to output a variable from FB_Init to the output of the function block. Can you describe the use case a little deeper in the question?

Comment: It is a declaration and I am calling `FB_init` method. I want to link FB's internal variable `output` to local variable `outputlocal`